# GRUB error. Ubuntu not loading?

Tags: grub2

I have a dual boot system: Windows 7 and Ubuntu. I installed Ubuntu without CD or USB. After a while, I got a problem using Ubuntu. When I boot to Ubuntu, I get a black background with "grub>" in the left. I tried to use different commands to fix it, but it does not work. Can anybody help me to log in?

Comment: Take a look at [Boot Repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair).

Answer (score 0):

You could use a [Boot Repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair) live disc to fix your grub. It has always worked fine for me.